# PresentViewController hides Navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to show navigation controller when i present `PresentViewController` for navigate a screen. I solved this problem, but i faced another problem. Problem is when i push to a screen that time back button is visible on next screen with navigation controller. But when i am trying to `PresentViewController`, that time navigation bar is visible but not back button.

Here is my code:

```
 - (IBAction)clickMeAction:(id)sender
 {
    ViewController1 *viewcontrol = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewID"];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontrol animated:YES]; // this is for push to viewcontroller


    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontrol];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; // This is for modalviewcontroller
 }
```

Here is my output:

with push:

[image]

with modal:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: When you open a window modally whether it is Navigation Contoller or any other it will not show Back button, you will have to set it manually.

Comment: yeah its a Navigation Controller.

Comment: When you open NC modally there will not be back button, you will have to set it manually.

Comment: yeah. i want reason. why its not showing, same thing also happens with push na? so why not in modal

Comment: [self presentViewController:viewcontrol animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @ Kirit Modi: this is not my requirement. My requirement is have to show navigationbar with backbutton

Comment: @SRNayak Because when you open any VC modally there is no stack of VC in memory, but using Navigation Controller it creates stack of VC's in memory to push and pop.

Comment: ohhh... yeah yeah i got it. Thanks  Yogesh Suthar :)

Comment: I think what @YogeshSuthar is trying to get across is that with a modal view controller, a back button does NOT show up by default. This is Apple's design. When you present a modal view, it looks like it is being presented on top of the current one, and therefore there is no back button. You can create your own bar button item that will dismiss the view, though.

Answer (score -1):

Method 1:

```
[navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
             [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
        }];
```

Method 2: in presentViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```